# how to set time hour in new Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

i want to set the hour of a day in javascript.
Now i am using this:

```
timestamp = new Date(2016, 7, 14),
```

How can i make this same date but extend with 2.00PM on the 14th?

Comment: `timestamp.setHour(14)`

Comment: Read the documentation of `new Date()`. You can specify the hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds as additional arguments.

Comment: `timestamp = new Date(2016, 7, 14, 14)`

Comment: [javascript time set hour](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+time+set+hour&oq=javascript+time+set+hour&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.436j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @blex The other arguments are optional. He just wants to set the hour, so they're not needed.

Comment: @Barmar, @Vld I was wrong in thinking that `new Date` would keep the current time. But it's only right when you provide no arguments.

Comment: @blex why? Would they otherwise be initialised to `duck` and `banana`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply looking at the `Date` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) can answer your question. Add another parameter to your instance of `Date` to define hours: `timestamp = new Date(2016, 7, 14, 14);` Note that hours are in military time; 14 hours is 2 PM.